# Use ConnLines on ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, desctools

I am trying to draw connection lines between several bars in a stacked barplot (`ggplot2`) in R. For this, I found the `ConnLines` function from the DescTools package. I aim for a similar result as shown in the [documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/DescTools/man/ConnLines.html).

```
taxa_bars <- ggplot(taxa_new, 
                    aes(x=Sample, y=Rel_abund, fill=Kingdom, width=0.5)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity", color="black") + 
  facet_wrap(~Individual, ncol=4) +
  ConnLines(taxa_new, beside=FALSE) +
  
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=12, face="bold", color = "black"),
  axis.text=element_text(size=11, face="bold", color = "black"),
  axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust=1.1, hjust=1.1),
  legend.title = element_text(size=6, face = "bold", color = "black"),
  legend.text = element_text(size=6, face = "bold", color = "black"),
  legend.key.size = unit(3, "mm"),
  panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
  panel.background = element_blank(),
  strip.background = element_rect(fill="white", color="white"),
  strip.text = element_text(face="bold", color="black")) +
  labs(x = "", y = "Abundance [%]", fill = "Taxa")
```

Throws the following error:

```
Error in barplot.default(..., plot = FALSE) : 'height' must be a vector or a matrix
```

`taxa_new` is a grouped data frame, since ggplot demands that. Converting it to a matrix within `ConnLines` does not do the job either. The plot works fine without the `ConnLines`. I assume that `ConnLines` is not compatible with `ggplot2` and only works with `barplot`?

Comment: Yep. You are right. ConnLines works only with base R plots. But if you are looking for a ggplot2 approach have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57263260/how-to-use-geom-bar-for-making-connected-bar-plot-in-ggplot2 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64375913/how-to-use-geom-bar-to-connect-stacked-bar-proportions-if-name-categorial-for-ba/64376210#64376210

Comment: Thanks @stefan !